# Using data base and C#

Tags: c#, database

[image]I have a table Questions and Answesrs in my DB, now I need to extract one by one each questions with it own answers, and by pressing the NEXT button to go to the second question.

```
  {    
  public partial class TakeTest : Form
   {
    public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
    private DataService dataService;
    private List<Category> categories;
    private List<Exam> tests;
    // private List<Question> questions;
    private Dictionary<Question, List<Answer>> qa;    

    public TakeTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataService = new DataService();
    }

    private void TakeTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // category
        categories = dataService.GetCategories();

        if (categories.Count > 0)
        {   
            cmbSelCategory.Items.AddRange(categories.ToArray());
            cmbSelCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

    }

    private void cmbSelCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Category selectedCategory = (Category)cmbSelCategory.SelectedItem;

        tests = dataService.GetTests(selectedCategory.Id);

        cmbSelTest.Items.Clear();
        if (tests.Count > 0)
        {
            cmbSelTest.Items.AddRange(tests.ToArray());
            cmbSelTest.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

    }
```

this is how i fill up category and test

QUESTION :Is using Dictionary 'Question, List'Answer'' a good idea? or how else i can do it

Comment: Hi, I cannot see your images (as I am at work) but assuming your questions are unique then storing them in a Dictionary should be fine. This would associate one question with a list of Answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already seem to have a `Question` class. Why not add an `Answers` property to that class and populate both the question details and all answers. Then you could create a `List<Question>`, which you can iterate from beginning to end.

It's harder to iterate a `Dictionary` than a `List`.

Acually, looking at your code more closely, you also seem to have an `Exam` class - this could contain a list of `Question`s and each `Question` could contain a list of `Answer`s.

Comment: i have the List<Question> used some where else... so i can use it here to... and i also tought about what you wrote...i`m just asking to see what would be better

Comment: "Acually, looking at your code more closely, you also seem to have an Exam class - this could contain a list of Questions and each Question could contain a list of Answers." - yes that is the idea :)